# Java Modular calculator

Tags: java

I'm attempting a code abbey problem and i'm very stuck. My goal for the program is to take in numbers with a math operation before the number and to do that math operation such as:

```
 5
+ 3
* 7
+ 10
* 2
* 3
+ 1
% 11

answer:
1
```

I feel as if i'm very close but cannot seem to get the answer I want to also add my answers up every single time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModularCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Initial Number:");
        int iN = in.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
            String a = in.next();
            int b = in.nextInt();

            if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
                System.out.println(b + iN);
            } else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                System.out.println(b * iN);
            } else {
                System.out.println(b % iN);
                sum = b + iN;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's happening, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want too either add the values or multiply and keep doing so until the modulus then to perform that over the sum

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your not doing proper algebra. Remember the order of operations. In your particular case, we can simplify it to only use the operations that you have, which are: `Multiply, Modulo, Addition`. Technically, Modulo isn't really standardized in where it is ordered, but I think most languages have Modulo as the same as Multiply/Divide, so a safe bet is to order it that way.

Since this is for a homework assignment clearly, I'm not going to fix your code for you. I will tell you though, that is definitely your issue. Think about how you would go about solving this...hint hint...don't read a token at a time...try reading more than that...

Comment: http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/modular-calculator actually no its not for homework its codeabey and im just trying to get better :(

Comment: Ok that explains a little bit. I've never seen that site before, but just at first glance I would steer clear. As I said, Modulo does not have a standard precedence, so if Modulo has high precedence the answer should be 4, and if it has low precedence then it would be 6. The fact that they're saying it's `1` seems to be a red flag to me.

Answer (score 0):

this will not work correctly ! because you are not working right , for example :

the answer of **1+2*3** equals to **7**
but your program will return **9** as answer

i think you must learn about postfix and prefix and how to use stack to achieve this goal , here is a link for study :

http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html

Comment: The same goes for you: please remove any code from your answer and explain in plain english. StackOverflow isn't a place where college/high-school students can come and have people do homework assignments for them.

Comment: @searchengine27 i don't understand why you downvoted my answer , you could edit my answer ...
ok , i will remove the code , i didn't know that !

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code...in fact, I appreciate that you wanted to help the question by posting code - I do. But in this case the person asking the question is trying to learn, so throwing a wall of code at them will not help them. In cases like this, in my opinion, it is better to explain it to them, and then allow them to solve the question.

Comment: @searchengine27 you are right , i must just explain the idea and send the link

Comment: Thank you for removing the code, I removed the downvote.

Comment: @searchengine27 thank you , i am new with stackoverflow , i learned sth new :))

Answer (score -1):

The problem you were having was that you weren't storing the value from last calculation properly. Al I did was just storing last calculated value in "iN".

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Initial Number:");
    int iN = in.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        String a = in.next();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
            iN = b + iN;
        } else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            iN = b * iN;
        } else {
            iN = b % iN;
            sum = b + iN;
        }
        System.out.println(iN);
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, please format your code. Secondly, this is for a homework assignment, so please remove any code from your answer and explain in plain english. StackOverflow isn't a place where college/high-school students can come and have people do homework assignments for them.

Comment: "iN" is the variable that should maintain value from the last calculation. Just added that line, "iN = //whatever calculation" and your code works

Comment: Honestly its not can you stop being like that? http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/modular-calculator its on codeabbey and im practicing

Comment: this will not work correctly ! because you are not working right , for example :

the answer of 1+2*3 equals to 7 but your program will return 9 as answer

Comment: This answer or the solution prescribed by AAnwar007, will only work if calculation is being done in an order, sequentially to be exact. Postfix and Infix notations are what you should learn but as far as Codeabbey goes, mine is the right answer. Cheers

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi, checkout Codeabbey. Don't downvote before looking at what they want done at Codeabbey.

Comment: I downvoted you because, for starters, you're posting code to somebody who is trying to learn how to code, which isn't going to help them learn at all, and secondly because you posted code, with literally no explanation of what you did, why the OP's solution didn't work, and why your solution resolves it. I already said why, and you still fail to pay attention.